# How to choose between a two tailed and one tailed T-test with scipy?

Tags: python, scipy

Scipy website seems to be down again :(

I am conducting a paired t test. But I am not sure how to choose between two-tailed and one-tailed (I need to use two-tailed). And also the ttest_reul only return t and p values. Anyway to find out degrees of freedom?  Many thanks

```
from scipy import stats
t_val_Input, p_val_Input = stats.ttest_rel(c1,c2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docstring of `ttest_rel`:

> ttest_rel(a, b, axis=0, nan_policy='propagate')
>
> Calculates the T-test on TWO RELATED samples of scores, a and b.
>
> This is a two-sided test for the null hypothesis that 2 related or
>   repeated samples have identical average (expected) values.

"Two-sided" means two-tailed.

The degrees of freedom is `n - 1`, where `n` is the number of pairs (i.e. `len(a)` or `len(b)`).

Comment: Any way to do a `one-sided` paired t-test in python ?